# Pandas: show only the rows that have the minimum value for each id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have a DataFrame like:

| id | length | width |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 12 | 12 |
| 2 | 13 | 15 |
| 4 | 14 | 19 |
| 4 | 11 | 13 |
| 7 | 34 | 67 |
| 7 | 33 | 64 |
| 7 | 40 | 78 |
| 7 | 22 | 33 |

What I want is, the number of the **id** should only show once AND it should only show the row with the minimum of the column of **length**.

The result would be:

| id | length | width |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 12 | 12 |
| 4 | 11 | 13 |
| 7 | 22 | 33 |

Comment: `df.sort_values(['id', 'length']).drop_duplicates('id')`.

Comment: @QuangHoang drop_duplicates('id')

Comment: That works! I forgot an important case. In the Column "length" I also have negative values. The positiv values should show the minimum but the negativ values should show the maximum values. How would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
out = df.loc[df.groupby('id')['length'].idxmin()]
Out[220]: 
   id  length  width
0   2      12     12
3   4      11     13
7   7      22     33
```

Comment: That works! I forgot an important case. In the Column "length" I also have negative values. The positiv values should show the minimum but the negativ values should show the maximum values. How would that work?

Comment: @Yokanishaa remove neg 1st df = df[df.length>=0] then run above

Comment: But I don't want to remove the negative values. They also need to show.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you updated your request in the comments of other answers. I have provided some code that should allow you to get the results you are expecting

```
df_pos = df.loc[df.mask(df['length'].ge(0)).dropna().groupby('id')['length'].idxmax()].reset_index().drop('index', axis = 1)
df_neg = df.loc[df.mask(df['length'].lt(0)).dropna().groupby('id')['length'].idxmin()].reset_index().drop('index', axis = 1)
df_con = pd.concat([df_pos, df_neg]).sort_values('id')
df_con
```